# SAS Proc Sql Date Range

Tags: sql, date, sas

I am a beginner in SAS, and I have a dummy question to ask.

I would like to pull member information based on their enrollment. I want year 2010 members but I don't want to restrict myself into `ineligible_date=20100101` and `eligible_date=20101231` because some people can enroll in 2009 and leave in 2014 etc. Can anyone tell me how to set up my date range?

The raw data looks like

```
ID       Eligibility  Ineligibility
123      8/1/2012     12/31/2012
1234     1/1/1997     8/31/2011
12345    4/1/2001     2/28/2010
1        7/1/2008     1/1/2010
2        5/1/2000     3/31/2010
3        11/1/2009    4/30/2013
456      9/1/2007     11/30/2009
789      3/1/1998     12/31/2010
1234567  2/1/2012     5/31/2012
1010     1/1/2010     1/1/2010
```

I would like the data to look like

```
ID     Eligibility  Ineligibility
1234   1/1/1997     8/31/2011
12345  4/1/2001     2/28/2010
2      5/1/2000     3/31/2010
3      11/1/2009    4/30/2013
789    3/1/1998     12/31/2010
```

Comment: Please give examples of data and what you want returned.  Your question is ambiguous because you talk about both years and dates.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
(ineligible_date >= 20100101 AND eligible_date <= 20101231) OR
(ineligible_date IS NULL AND eligible_date <= 20101231)
```

Comment: No. It will return all the data in all years.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your data the following logic can get what you want

```
if eligibility < '01jan2010'd   and Ineligibility > '01jan2010'd  ;
```